# Link domain branch.io

Tags: branch.io

On the dashboard, I have two domains: “Default Link Domain” and “Alternative Link Domain”, but when I create a new link using the API, I get a link without this domain, something like this “app.test-app ". It’s very important for me that my link is without a “test”. And also I don’t understand how it works, how this domain appears in my link. Could you please explain it to me?

Here is my branch.json

{
    "debugMode": false,
    "liveKey": "key_live_****",
    "testKey": "key_test_****",
    "useTestInstance": false,
    "delayInitToCheckForSearchAds": true,
    "appleSearchAdsDebugMode": true
}

When I set up my application, I added a test key to info.plist and forgot about it. After I changed it to a live key, everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A Branchster here -

By default your Branch app has two modes - Live and Test. When you are using the API to generate a new link make sure you are passing in your Live API key. If you use your Test Mode API key then you'll get corresponding test link like "yourapp-app.app.link/xxxx"

You can read more about it here - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/advanced-settings-configuration